# Wireless performance on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

Is there something I should do to my networking configuration in Ubuntu to better the performance of my wireless connection?  I'm on a netbook dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.10.  I pick up much stronger wifi signal when in Windows than Ubuntu.  As soon as I boot Ubuntu, it will connect to the network with a stronger signal, and then loses signal very quickly.  After it dies, I can't reconnect.  I've tested this on a couple of different networks with the same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try upgrading to 10.04 since it comes with a newer kernel which means newer drivers, better wifi (maybe). Or you can use a newer kernel from a PPA (Personal Package Archive). (Anyway, this happens usually quite often, in Windows you get a better signal due to the better driver.)

Comment: I was planning on upgrading anyway, but your suggestion seems to be the solution.  I get about 40% more signal strength on my home network using 10.04.  Thanks!

Comment: Later if you will want more or will have some problem, you will be able to upgrade only your kernel from a PPA for example. (PPAs are a great stuff. ;P)